# Clicking a link will open a new div element in a lightbox with form inside it

Tags: php, html, forms, lightbox

I have an idea which I don't know how to start, but I want to achieve: When I click a link, I want to open a div element inside lightbox which has HTML form done for inserting data into database. Now I know how to make a form and fields necessary. Once the form is completed, when the use clicks submit button, I want that existing div element to vanish, and a new div open in lightbox, telling the user: The data has been added to database successfully. And close the lightbox after few moments.

How should I start about doing this? I have a link and lightbox imported and know how to use lightbox.
I would appreciate your help. Cheers!

If you need more information, tell and I will edit this post.

Ok, I've been bugging with this entire day, and managed to get it to work.

**The jQuery code:**

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.data-window').click(function() {

            //Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});

// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , .data-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

**The Form that I've made:**

```
<div id="data-box" class="data-popup">

<h3>Ispunite formu za unošenje proizvoda</h3>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td>Kategorija:</td>
    <td><select class="select" name="kategorija">
    <option class="option" selected>Odaberite...</option>
    <option class="option" value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option class="option" value="PC">PC</option>
    <option class="option" value="Tablet">Tablet</option>
    <option class="option" value="Periferije">Periferije</option>
    <option class="option" value="Dijelovi">Dijelovi</option>
    <option class="option" value="Audio">Audio</option>
    <option class="option" value="Mobitel">Mobitel</option>
    <option class="option" value="Monitor">Monitor</option>
    <option class="option" value="Televizor">Televizor</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Proizvod:</td>
    <td><select class="select" name="proizvod">
    <option class="option" selected>Odaberite...</option>
    <option class="option" value="Prijenosno Računalo">Prijenosno Računalo</option>
    <option class="option" value="Stolno Računalo">Stolno Računalo</option>
    <option class="option" value="Džepno Računalo">Džepno Računalo</option>
    <option class="option" value="Računalni Dodaci">Računalni Dodaci</option>
    <option class="option" value="Komponente">Komponente</option>
    <option class="option" value="Zvučna Oprema">Zvučna Oprema</option>
    <option class="option" value="Mobilni Uređaji">Mobilni Uređaji</option>
    <option class="option" value="Monitor">Monitor</option>
    <option class="option" value="Televizor">Televizor</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Proizvođač:</td>
    <td><select class="select" name="proizvodac">
    <option class="option" selected>Odaberite...</option>
    <option class="option" value="Acer">Acer</option>
    <option class="option" value="Asus">Asus</option>
    <option class="option" value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option class="option" value="Dell">Dell</option>
    <option class="option" value="HP">HP</option>
    <option class="option" value="Lenovo">Lenovo</option>
    <option class="option" value="Alienware">Alienware</option>
    <option class="option" value="Sony">Sony</option>
    <option class="option" value="Compaq">Compaq</option>
    <option class="option" value="IBM">IBM</option>
    <option class="option" value="Gateway">Gateway</option>
    <option class="option" value="CyberPower">CyberPower</option>
    <option class="option" value="Alcatel">Alcatel</option>
    <option class="option" value="Amazon">Amazon</option>
    <option class="option" value="Archos">Archos</option>
    <option class="option" value="DataWind">DataWind</option>
    <option class="option" value="FlipKart">FlipKart</option>
    <option class="option" value="Huawei">Huawei</option>
    <option class="option" value="iBall">iBall</option>
    <option class="option" value="Karbonn">Karbonn</option>
    <option class="option" value="Lava">Lava</option>
    <option class="option" value="LG">LG</option>
    <option class="option" value="Micromax">Micromax</option>
    <option class="option" value="Microsoft">Microsoft</option>
    <option class="option" value="Milagrow">Milagrow</option>
    <option class="option" value="Panasonic">Panasonic</option>
    <option class="option" value="Swipe">Swipe</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Model:</td>
    <td><input class="input" type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Slika:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="slika"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Naziv:</td>
    <td><input class="input" type="text" name="naziv" placeholder="Naziv"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Opis:</td>
    <td><textarea class="textarea" name="opis"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cijena:</td>
    <td><input class="input" type="text" name="cijena" placeholder="Cijena"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>

<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" />
<input class="button" type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>

</div>
```

Now I need to be able to send the data into the database from this form, hopefully avoiding the possibility for SQL injection (I've been reading tutorials, and it only confused me so much more..)
I think I'd be able to manage the insertion of the data into the database by myself, but here is the thing that I want to achieve: There is an input field to insert the image. How do I upload data to the database and at the same time upload image to the folder "images" on my server and retrieve the url of the image in a special variable (example: "images\HP ENVY Y700.png") and then what's in that variable (the url) to be inserted into the column (Slika) in database?
Also, when I upload the selected picture, I need it to be cut in 200x200 dimension, so that there will be 2 images that will be uploaded. One full size .png and the other 200x200 .gif into the same directory. and as I said, I need to retrieve the url of the both images actually, because I have div element which displays the cropped image and that image will be lightbox link to full size image.

This may sound very confusing, but I tried to explain the best I could. I hope you will understand what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: Please also supply a (non-)working example so that your problem is more specific. I suggest you consult the Lightbox API, or use JQuery to achieve what you want. If you do not know how to use either one of them, refresh your javascript knowledge.

Comment: I have found some tutorial, I hope I will be able to understand it. If not, I will post back here.